# как отправить фото в телеграмм бота

Tags: python

Не могу получить фото из папки на сервере которую бот должен выгружать мне в чат.. сделал так, но не вышло..

Как сделать чтобы бот отправлял фото сразу же, как только появляется движение?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import config #файл с настройками
import telegram
import os
import subprocess
import sys
import shlex
import datetime
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from imp import reload #модуль для перезагрузки (обновления) других модулей

from datetime import datetime
from telegram.ext import Updater
updater = Updater(token=config.token)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
```

процедура выполнения скрипта и тот код который пытался внедрить чтобы бот отправлял фото мне в чат из папки, куда motion сохраняет снимки движения объекта в поле зрения камеры.. формат снимков `{:%d-%b-%Y-%R}.jpg` то есть `29-Jun-2017-18:54.jpg`

```
def camon(bot, update):
    reload(config) 
    user = str(update.message.from_user.id)
    if user in config.admin: #если пользовательский id в списке admin то команда выполняется
        run_command("/home/ignat/bot_serv/scriptcamon.sh")
        photo = '/media/root/server/motion/{:%d-%b-%Y-%R}.jpg'.format(datetime.now())
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=textoutput)
        bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, open(photo, 'rb'))
```

---

ну вообще, думал реализовать отслеживание нового файла отдельно через watchdog или простым циклом , то есть в другом демоне а не в основном коде бота таким кодом

```
import telegram

bot = telegram.Bot('TOKEN')

def main():
    # Тут должно быть отслеживание нового файла и вызов коллбэка


def on_new_file_created(new_file_name):
    photo = '/media/root/server/motion/{:%d-%b-%Y-%R}.jpg'.format(new_file_name)
    bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, open(photo, 'rb'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `бот отправлял фото сразу же, как только появляется движение` – как по-вашему он должен узнать о том, что появилось движение?

Comment: Начните что ли с простых отдельных задач: просто отправить фото в чат, отреагировать на движение.

Comment: `но не вышло` – а что вышло? Если есть какие-то ошибки, добавьте их текст в вопрос ([edit]), если получился иной результат — расскажите, что за результат.

Comment: @Igor, похоже, я своей правкой отменил вашу, ждавшую проверки. Сможете достать из кэша и повторить?

Comment: Добавил ваш комментарий. Можно и не жать Ctrl+K, а вручную поставить 4 пробела перед каждой строкой. Ничего страшного, разбирайтесь.

Comment: По сути вопроса: чтобы вам можно было помочь и дать конкретный ответ, от вас требуется четкая постановка вопроса. 1) Одна конкретная решаемая задача, например "как отправить картинку" или "как детектировать появление картинки в папке" или что-то еще подобное. Вопрос "как сделать А, потом Б и потом В" — не годится, это три разных вопроса.

Comment: 2) Опишите четко желаемый результат и фактически полученный результат. Приведите **минимальный** пример кода, который воспроизводит получаемый вами результат.

Comment: от бота требуется отследить появление нового файла в директории и отправить этот самый новый файл в чат

Comment: И это два разных вопроса: Отслеживание файла может быть полезно само по себе, без связи с телеграм-ботом. А отправка картинок в чат тоже полезна сама по себе, независимо от причины и источника картинки. Сайт у нас так устроен, в вопросе должно быть что-то одно. Про две проблемы можно задать два вопроса. Подробнее прочитайте пожалуйста тут: [Два или несколько вопросов в одном](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3169).

Comment: тогда просто отслеживание фото как-то реализовать можно? кстати,  проект лежит здесь ( https://github.com/ignatiy/telegram_bot-python/tree/master/bot_serv )